# Local.xml change or only adding files?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I found out, that **frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml**

does control the parts of my bundle-pages that I want to edit. So, alright I could edit this file directly but I learnt, that isn't recommended due to upgradability-problems.

So, what would I alternatively need to do? Do I just need to add a new file 
**frontend/my_package/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml**

like this and put all my stuff in there, or do I also need to reference something into my layout within local.xml? How would I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Actually just tried it myself and: Yes. You just need to actually add the corresponding folders to your package/theme.

Comment: Yep that is the right way to do it. local.xml is also useful in some case like when you want to change the position of block on your page or remove an existing one or add one. 
There is still a lot you may discover on magento theming but you are in the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes simply make this file in your theme and then you can edit it to fit with your design.

The other option which is a bit more complex is to update the template via some layout xml and then this new template will be used and you can add it to the base folder with whatever new path you like. I would suggest that your changes are probably theme specific and so should be made by making the changes in your theme.